# Haskell parallel computation using an STArray

Tags: arrays, haskell, parallel-processing, monads, state-monad

I'm trying to do computation in parallel, and write the results to an STArray. I think this code shows what I'm trying to do. However, I'm getting compile errors.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Parallel
import Data.Array.ST

main = do
    arr <- newArray ((0,0), (5,5)) 0 :: ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) Int)
    runSTArray $ do
        par (writeArray arr (1,1) 17) (writeArray arr (2,2) 23)
        return arr
    print arr
```

How should I do this?

Comment: I think you should use [Repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) for parallel array operations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use `newArray`, which has the type `ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) Int)`. However, you use it in the body of the `main` function, which means that everything you `do` must have an `IO` type. `ST` is not `IO`, so the types cannot match.

You should first move the `newArray` into a context where you have access to the `ST` monad. This context is of course available in the body of `runSTArray`, so change the body to:

```
    runSTArray $ do
        arr <- newArray ((0,0), (5,5)) 0 :: ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) Int)
        par (writeArray arr (1,1) 17) (writeArray arr (2,2) 23)
        return arr
```

Then, you need to rethink how `par` behaves. `par` is for creating parallel *pure* computations, and cannot be used for monadic actions; monads cannot generally be parallelized at all. In particular, the `ST` monad doesn't even offer any alternatives for parallel computations; since parallel writes to an array can lead to race conditions (what happens if you overwrite the same cell? Which write will count, and which one won't?), it is unsafe to allow parallelism here. You must change the array in sequence:

```
    runSTArray $ do
        arr <- newArray ((0,0), (5,5)) 0 :: ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) Int)
        writeArray arr (1,1) 17
        writeArray arr (2,2) 23
        return arr
```

However, the writes aren't expensive; it's the calculations of the values that might be expensive. Suppose that you want to calculate `17` and `23` on the fly; you can then do the following:

```
let a = someLongCalculation 12534
    b = a `par` (someLongCalculation 24889)
writeArray arr (1, 1) a
writeArray arr (2, 2) b
```

Finally, you must realize that `runSTArray` returns the result array, so you must store it like this:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Parallel
import Data.Array.ST

main =
  let pureArr =
        runSTArray $ do
          arr <- newArray ((0,0), (5,5)) 0 :: ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) Int)
          writeArray arr (1,1) 17
          writeArray arr (2,2) 23
          return arr
  in print pureArr
```

I don't think that `STArray`s are the correct solution here. You should use a more powerful array library like [`repa`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) in situations where you need parallel symmetrical array computations.

Comment: Thanks, I had figured out how to do sequential reads and writes. It looks like I was stuck because, as you point out, the par monad does not allow me to parallelize those actions. I'll have to look into how to achieve parallel writes to an array using Repa.

Comment: It's the `ST` monad that doesn't let you do parallelism.  You could do it in `IO` with `forkIO` and company, if you liked, though.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Could you elaborate? Would this allow me to write to the same array from all forked threads?

Comment: [Mutable arrays](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html) exist for both `ST` as well as `IO`, so you can use them from `IO` if you don't want the type guarantees that `ST` offers. Also, please be careful about racing when it comes to parallel modifications of mutable arrays.

Comment: Yep.  You can write in parallel to an `IO` array, although if multiple threads try writing to or reading from the _same_ array entries, thread safety goes straight out the window.

Comment: Insightful answer, thank you. I wasn't even looking for this, I just ended up here and liked it.

Answer (score 1):

`par` is for composing pure operations in parallel. you're composing effectful operations. you can't use par. Furthermore, parallelism *is* an effect (at least when composed with mutation), and isn't available to you in the ST monad. I can't give you advice on the right way to structure your code, because things are too cut down to see what you're actual problem domain is. My general advice, however, is, to use explicit concurrency constructs like fork (in the IO monad) *or* to use pure operations rather that mutatey arrays.